# Keeping connections with VcXsrv to applications in hyper-v machine

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, vcxsrv

I'm running X-Applications on Ubuntu in Hyper-V and connecting to them with VcXsrv. After my computer goes to sleep for a while the connections are lost, i.e. the X-Applications windows are no longer visible. The applications are howerver still running for a while on the virtual machine (according to `ps aux`).

Is there a way to make sure X-Applications on a vm running locally are still there even after the computer went to Sleep for a while